# Having trouble installing MySQL Community Server on new RHEL 6.8 instance

Tags: mysql, redhat, rhel6, rhel7

I'm having trouble installing MySQL 5.7.12 on RHEL 6.8.

The first RPM I downloaded was for RHEL 7.0. This is a brand new instance, and I stupidly assumed it would be RHEL 7. It's not.

So my installation failed with errors like:

```
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-5.7.12-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
       Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-5.7.12-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
       Requires: systemd
Error: Package: mysql-community-libs-5.7.12-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
       Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
Error: Package: 2:postfix-2.6.6-6.el6_7.1.x86_64 (@rhel-x86_64-server-6)
       Requires: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
```

That's when I looked at the version and found it was 6.8. So I did:

```
sudo rpm -e mysql57-community-release-el7-8.noarch
```

and removed it. I added the repo for RHEL6 with:

```
wget http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el6-8.noarch.rpm
```

and:

```
sudo yum localinstall mysql57-community-release-el6-8.noarch.rpm
```

and:

```
sudo yum install mysql-community-server
```

But I still get these failures:

```
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-5.7.12-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
       Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-5.7.12-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
       Requires: systemd
Error: Package: mysql-community-libs-5.7.12-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
       Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
Error: Package: 2:postfix-2.6.6-6.el6_7.1.x86_64 (@rhel-x86_64-server-6)
       Requires: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
       Removing: mysql-libs-5.1.73-7.el6.x86_64 (@rhel-x86_64-server-6)
```

Notice that first line. It still says `el7`. Did removing the `rpm` for MySQL RHEL7 not get rid of everything? Also, it still says it requires `systemd`, but there's no `systemd` anywhere I can find on this 6.8 install. I appreciate the help, I know that I'm missing something basic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

systemd was only adopted in RHEL 7, so RHEL6 doesn't have it.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd

If I were you I would try something like this:

http://sharadchhetri.com/2013/12/26/install-mysql-server-5-6-in-centos-6-x-and-red-hat-6-x-linux/